# Issue with line count in the loop

Tags: shell, loops, for-loop

I have a script as below.

```
mount=/transfer/input
rm src/cb.log
array=( $(find ${mount}  -type f \( -name "Turbine_DATA*" -o -name "GT_Data*"  -o -name "INSIGHTS_data*" \) -printf '%f\n' ))
for i in "${array[@]}";do
        echo $i >>src/cb.log

Filecount=`find ${mount} -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "$i" | wc -l`
echo $Filecount>> src/cb.log;
done
```

I am facing below issue.
Although the file Turbine_DATA has 3 lines of data in that but the Filecount is still showing as 1. I am able to do wc -l on that file in the /transfer/input directory where the file is present and I can see 3 count there.

The point to note here that I am running the script from /NAS/Files directory.
Is this the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filecount is the number of files, not the total number of lines in those files.
That's why it's named **File**count, not **Line**count.
It's counting the number of files with the given name (I assume there can be multiple files of the same name in different subdirectories).

However, for a correct understanding you should probably consult the author of that script - it's not clear what information it should write to cb.log.

Comment: I may be drunk not to realize that :D.. Thanks @Hans-Martin Mosner. I think i got really confused with the wc -l